# How to Pass the encrypted response from nodejs to client side through ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, ajax

I'm trying to encrypt the password that is sent through ajax in json format. The encryption logic is in my server.js

How do I pass the encrypted response from server.js. I'm able to encrypt but I'm stuck on passing this encrypted response

server.js:

```
    app.post('/mylink',function(request,reply){ 
    var data = JSON.stringify(request.body.jsonblob);
    var pwd = request.body.jsonblob.Password;
    var cipher = crypto.createCipher(algorithm,password)
    var crypted = cipher.update(pan,'utf8','hex')
    crypted += cipher.final('hex');
    console.log("crypted"+crypted);
    reply.send(crypted);
     });
```

ajax call in my html page:

```
     var json_data = JSON.stringify({
                    "jsonblob" : {    
                         "Password": password   
                    }
                    });


          $.ajax({ 

            url:"/mylink",
            type: "post",               
            dataType: "json",      
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: json_data,                       
            success:function(response){
                if(response.status === "success")
                {
                    console.log(crypted);
                }

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThtrown) {
                console.log("error " +textStatus);
                }


          });
```

Comment: Use HTTPS and this will happen securely & transparently all by itself?

Comment: If you request json you need to respond with json. Doesn't make sense returning a password to client

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any Use-Case where you would want to return a encrypted Password to the Client. You encrypt and decrypt your Passwords on the Server to protect your Password from being stored in the Database in cleartext.

I think you might be confusing the encryption of a password and generating a JSON Web Token, which you can later use to authenticate a user. In that case you would want to return the Token to be saved on the Client Side. There are a Number of great articles about how you can go about building a secure Node Backend. Here is my favorite:

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/securing-node-js-restful-apis-with-json-web-tokens-9f811a92bb52

Also, if you want to protect your Passwords for being clear in the content of your request, make sure you use HTTPS.